# How to check whether java plugin is enabled or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an .aspx page which consists of applet code.  In order to run this, the browser must have an active Java plugin.

Is there any way to check whether a Java plugin is installed and enabled, using Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.navigator.javaEnabled()//true if java enabled 

window.navigator.plugins // will give u all the plugins installed in the browser
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to go for the method recommended by Oracle

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    if (deployJava.versionCheck('1.6+')) {            
        var url = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/deployment/webstart/examples/Notepad.jnlp";

        <!-- you can also invoke deployJava.runApplet here -->
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0'); 
    } else {
        document.location.href="http://oracle.com";
    }
</script>
```

This is taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jreVersionCheck.html

You should also take a look at Java Deployment Toolkit
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit

Comment: I had deployjava script through which i can find weather the java plugin is installed or not but i want weather it is enabled or not